# Cant insert float mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have some problem.

When I try insert or update some field(float or double) I insert 0.

when I  try to insert numb 1.15 it's  ok. but when I try to insert 0.15 it insert 0. I don't know why.

Please help me to fix this problem.
I used php
its my code

```
$pr =0.15;

    "UPDATE `sales_products_info` SET price =".$pr.", profit = profit - ".$pr."  where id = ".$id
```

Comment: Try to wrap the float with single quotes

Comment: Try using bind variables

Comment: what's the table definition? Did you check for warnings?  i.e. via `mysqli_get_warnings()` or `SHOW WARNINGS`

Comment: Caveat: not directly related to this problem, but money should not be represented as `FLOAT`, use `DECIMAL` instead. Float will bite you: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info

Answer (score 0):

You missed single quotes in your SQL:

```
$id=1;
$pr =0.15;
$sql = "UPDATE `test` SET price ='".$pr."', profit = profit - '".$pr."'  where id= '".$id."' ";
```